# How to resize a particular cell in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to shrink the size of particular cell. I tried the following code but it resizes every column.

```
table = Table(data, colWidths=[1.9*inch] * 5)
```

I also tried this code in table `style`

```
style = TableStyle([
('colWidths', (3, 3), (3, 3), 0.5*cm )
])
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I resize a particular cell, say cell number `3,3`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a list to `colWidths` and/or `rowHeights` with different sizes? Something like:

```
table = Table(data, colWidths=[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2], 
              rowHeights=[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2])
```